# Passing settings via interfaces in Java - possible?

Tags: java, java-8, interface

Let's assume I have two classes.

```java
public class Banana extends Fruit{    
    public Banana() {
        this.setTitle("Banana");
        this.setSize("Medium");
        this.setState("Rotten");
    }
}
```

```java
public class Sausage extends Meat{    
    public Sausage() {
        this.setTitle("Sausage");
        this.setSize("Medium");
        this.setState("Rotten");
    }
}
```

Is there a way to introduce an interface (probably with default methods) that would hold the common settings? Both original extensions should remain.

I've googled interfaces and default methods for about an hour and asked about this on a Java chat server, but I'm still confused.

Comment: Interfaces don't have instance fields. They can't hold state.

Comment: First thing you need to have a common class which is being extended by others. You can't keep common settings until n unless Fruit and Meat meet somewhere common.

Comment: if I had a common class, this would not be an interesting question anymore. For the sake of science, let's assume they don't. Can I still accomplish anything with interfaces and default cases?

Comment: You can't do this *directly.*  I think what your basically asking for here is multiple inheritance, and that concept seems to give the Java language designers a bad rash.  You can implement something like it yourself though.

Comment: @markspace any examples of how it could be done for the provided classes?

Comment: See my answer that I just posted!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly. I think what your basically asking for here is multiple inheritance, and that concept seems to give the Java language designers a bad rash. You can implement something like it yourself though.

Assume you have an interface `Food`

```
public interface Food {    
    void setTitle(String s);
    void setSize(String s);
    void setState(String s);
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
public class BaseFood implements Food {  
    private String title;  
    private String size;  
    private String state;  
    // setters and getters...
}
```

And then this:

```
public class Banana extends Fruit implements Food {    
    private BaseFood food = new Food();
    public Banana() {
        food.setTitle("Banana");
        food.setSize("Medium");
        food.setState("Rotten");
    }
}
```

For completeness, here is `Sausage`, it's basically the same as `Banana`:

```
public class Sausage extends Meat implements Food {    
    private BaseFood food = new Food();
    public Sausage() {
        food.setTitle("Kielbasa");
        food.setSize("Medium");
        food.setState("Tasty");
    }
}
```

This is called "delegation" where you delegate the implementation of some interface in Java to another object, only declaring that it implements a common interface but then just calling methods on a private instance that actually implements that interface.  It's basically manual multiple inheritance.

It's common enough that my IDE (NetBeans) will do most of the work for me.  Given an interface and a private instance member that implements that interface, it will write all the methods that one needs to publicly implement that interface.  It works OK but can generate a lot of boilerplate.  I somewhat wish that the Java folks would at least come up with a partial solution in the language for "the multiple inheritance problem."

EDIT: You said no base classes in common, but then you said this:

> You cannot create a base class in this case since it's Java with its single inheritance - and both Sausage and Banana are already extending something. Unless I'm missing something you can see...

If you can change the inheritance, you can create a common base class:

```
class Food { ...
class Fruit extends Food {...
class Banana extends Fruit {...
class Meat extends Food {...
class Sausage extends Meat { ...
```

But my answer assumed that you cannot do this for whatever reason.

Comment: I think I get the point, but the answer does not include the sausage for completeness, I guess someone was hungry, so the sausage disappeared.

Comment: Sausage basically looks just like Banana (no puns intended).

Comment: Thank you for working with the assumption you mentioned. Otherwise, the question would be trivial, really. Great answer, awesome explanation!

Comment: I've ran the code... and I'm sad. Not only Netbeans requires implementation of abstract methods for Banana, but it also says Food is abstract and cannot be instantiated... Something is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The question is: what kind of properties do you want to hold?

You can declare *public static final* fields in interfaces, just like in any class:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    String PROPERTY = "MyProperty";
}
```

If that's not enough, you'd probably have to use *inheritance* instead of an interface and store common properties there, in an abstract object.

Comment: Could you provide examples of how it could be done for the given classes?

Comment: @Governator It can"t. You want instance fields. Interfaces don't have instance fields. Only static final fields.

Comment: @JBNizer, confused it with *default* methods. Updated the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are used to define some common *behaviour*. If you need common *state*, you should go with a base class which you can make also abstract if it will not be instantiated directly.

Comment: You cannot create a base class in this case since it's Java with its single inheritance - and both Sausage and Banana are already extending something. Unless I'm missing something you can see...

Comment: You can have a baseclass called Product (seems appropriate in your case) and make Fruit and Meat extend that one first.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces only define a contract that implementations must fulfill, but usually do not expose any implementation detail itself. (not considering default methods here)

What you mean is probably an `abstract` class or a common superclass that inherits those common properties to subclasses. Those classes can hold a concrete state.

```
/**
 * The contract for each food.
 * You can get its title, size and its state. Also, the state can be changed.
 */
public interface Food {
    String getTitle();
    String getSize();
    String getState();
    void setState(String state);
}
```

Now, an `abstract` class can define common behaviour:

```
public class AbstractFood implements Food {

    private String title;
    private String size;
    private String state;

    public AbstractFood(String title, String size, String state) {
        this.title = title;
        this.size = size;
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return null;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSize() {
        return null;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public String getState() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

And those class can have arbitary subclasses, for example a `Fruit`.

```
public class Fruit extends AbstractFood {

    public Fruit(String title, String size, String state) {
        super(title, size, state);
    }
}
```

Define a class `Banana`, which is a `Fruit`:

```
public class Banana extends Fruit {

    public Banana(String size, String state) {
        super("Banana", size, state);
    }
}
```

Coming back to the user of the `Food` interface, you can now apply common behaviour on all type of food without knowing any implementation detail. You can, for example, change the state of all bananas to rotten:

```
for (Fruit fruit : fruits) {
    if (fruit.getTitle().equals("Banana")) {
        fruit.setState("Rotten");
    }
}
```